# How to get a line in the listview under the text

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmd73.png)]

something like this:

```
SizedBox(
          height: 30,
           child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 13, left: 25),
                        child: ListView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          children: [
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: const Text(
                                'Arts',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 151, 151, 151)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: const Text(
                                'Biography',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 151, 151, 151)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: const Text(
                                'Romance',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 151, 151, 151)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: const Text(
                                "Thriller",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 151, 151, 151)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: const Text(
                                "Fiction",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 151, 151, 151)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: const Text(
                                "Crime",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 151, 151, 151)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: const Text(
                                "Movies",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 151, 151, 151)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: const Text(
                                "Religious",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 151, 151, 151)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: const Text(
                                "Philosophy",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 151, 151, 151)),
                            ),
                         )
                      ],
                   ),
               )),
           ],
       ),
   ),
```

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[mre]" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 1):

Use [TabBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html) instead

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatelessWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      initialIndex: 1,
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('TabBar Widget'),
          bottom: const TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(
                
                text: 'Tab 1'
              ),
              Tab(
                text: 'Tab 2'
              ),
              Tab(
                 text: 'Tab 3',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: const TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Text("It's cloudy here"),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text("It's rainy here"),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text("It's sunny here"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```